# Multiple custom controls affects control visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls

Ok, this is going to be a 1000ft long question, but there's a lot to cover so here goes:

I am creating a **paged items control**, the purpose of which is to display very large collections in a paged format. I've created a repository on **GitHub** which can be found [here](https://github.com/mike-eason/Paged-Items-Control-WPF). I have removed any styling for simplicity.

Upon starting the application, it looks like this:

[image: The main window]

This is pretty straightforward really, there's navigation buttons, an *items per page* selector but that isn't really important. The **problem** here is when you click the button **"Open New Window"**.

This will open a new `MainWindow`, but on the first window, the collection **disappears**, as shown below:

[image: Disappearing content]

The image above shows the **old** window in front, as you can see, there is no list of content as there is on the new window.

---

So, after smashing my head against a wall for a couple of hours, I am in need of assistance. I'll provide an overview of how the project is structured.

**AnagramPagedItemsControl**

The **control** being used for displaying the content is a custom control called `AnagramPagedItemsControl`, it is responsible for handling navigation between pages. I think the key property here is the `PagedCollection`.

The `PagedCollection` dependency property holds the collection which is bound to the `Models` property in the `TestItemsViewModel`.

**TestItemsViewModel**

This is the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`, each window instance should create it's own view model. The `CreateTestItems()` method is responsible for creating the list of test items.

**LazyPagedCollection**

The purpose of this collection is to encapsulate the logic of a paged observable collection, it only loads pages when they are *needed*, hence the laziness.

It exposes methods like `NextPage` which are called in the `AnagramPagedItemsControl` when the user clicks on the various navigation buttons. The view model can also call navigation on the `LazyPagedCollection`, this allows the view model to call navigation without having to go through the view to do it.

---

**TL;DR**

When I create a new `Window`, the content of the previous window disappears. The problem is almost certainly with the control however I am stuck as to how to fix the problem.

---

This is quite a large problem to look at so I'd be very grateful for anyone who can look into it. Again, the source code is [here](https://github.com/mike-eason/Paged-Items-Control-WPF), please feel free to suggest alternatives or pick out anything that I may have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had some time to spare, so:

The problem is the setter for the `CollectionView` property in the style for `AnagramPagedItemsControl` in `generic.xaml`.

This does *not* instantiate a new `ListBox` every time the style is applied; it will just create the one `ListBox`, the first time the style is created, and *use that value over, and over again*. So in effect, every instance of `MainWindow` shares the same `ListBox`.

You can see this by setting the `Tag` property of PART_`CollectionView` to (for instance) "1" in `SetupBindings(ItemsControl PART_CollectionView)`. When you open a new window, you'll see that `PART_CollectionView.Tag` contains the same value you previously assigned.

Comment: It had me baffled for a while too. I don't like to be baffled :)